# Evaluar resultados de una función

Tags: python, api, funciones

Estoy tratando de obtener unos datos por medio de una API, estoy utilizando "paginación" por medio del parametro "offset" de la misma API.

Todo funciona muy bien, ya traigo la información sin problemas y en los pedazos que quiera. Debido a que no sé cuántos registros son, utilicé un while para recorrerlos todos, el detalle es que al ser while, puedo continuar de manera infinita.

La duda es ¿como puedo evaluar cuando ya no tenga registros que entregar?

Este es el codigo:

```
def get_static_host_list(url,offset):
    payload={}
    headers = {
        'Authorization': token_type+' '+access_token,
        'Cookie': 'GSID=c74c560a6e90cb1d3395c36837a95156'
        }
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
    static_host_list = json.loads(response.text)
    for x in static_host_list["_embedded"]["items"]:
        id_list = x["id"]
        name_list = x["name"]
        if(id_list != None): 
            print(id_list,name_list)
        else:
            print("no hay mas valores")
```

Ya trate con un if/else, pero no cae en ningun momento. ¿Alguna idea?

Gracias!

Comment: `id_list` no devuelve vacío `" "` en vez de `None`? Más bien no debería de existir ya que no hay más datos

Answer (score 0):

Hice la prueba buscando un "vacio" y revisar si la variable existe sin suerte. Como les comentaba, estaba trabajando con API's y paginación, por lo que siempre había información (aunque no estuviera relacionada con lo que buscaba.

Al final termine evaluando si la respuesta eran solo corchetes "[]", quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
def get_static_host_list(url,offset):
    payload={}
    headers = {
        'Authorization': token_type+' '+access_token,
        'Cookie': 'GSID=c74c560a6e90cb1d3395c36837a95156'
        }
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
    static_host_list = json.loads(response.text)
    if(static_host_list["_embedded"]["items"]!=[]):
       for x in static_host_list["_embedded"]["items"]:
           id_list = x["id"]
           name_list = x["name"] 
           print(id_list,name_list)
    else:
        print("no hay más registros\n Tarea terminada!")
        exit()
```

Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Christian.

Saludos.

Comment: Que bueno que hayas resulto el error y pues, practicamente era eso lo que decia ya que las respuestas las tienes en un array o lista por lo que es correcto `[]` que representa un array vacio :)